# cx_Oracle.so: undefined symbol:PyUnicodeUCS2_AsEncodedString

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am having issiues installing cx_oracle. I have installed oracle instantclient and cx_oracle oracle packages ones installed i am getting this error while importing cx_oracle. i am running ubuntu 11.10 as host.

```
import cx_Oracle
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Oracle.so: undefined symbol:PyUnicodeUCS2_AsEncodedString
```

any one have any idea how to resolve this issue

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably your Python install uses another unicode format (ucs4) and cx_oracle was compiled with ucs2.

You can install cx_Oracle 5.0.4 with the unicode flag. That worked for me but there is some bug: [strange Oracle error: "invalid format text"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463919/strange-oracle-error-invalid-format-text)

Or compile the latest cx_oracle yourself.
http://mrpolo.com.ve/?p=178 (its some language i don't know but it helped)

Answer (score 1):

I addition to @froZieglers answer. When I came along the `cx_Oracle` page there was no "...Unicode..."-Variant to download anymore. Luckily compiling it myself from source was not a big a hassle then I expected.

Here a summary about what I did (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 64bit):

- install the proper **Oracle XE client rpm** with alien (11g, 64bit, etc...)

  - it installs th `/u01/...`, I had to adjust `.profile` too, of course.
- [download](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/) **cx_Oracle source-tar**, untar, cd into

  - I did the `ln -s` command on the so-lib on Oracle, as said in `BUILD` text file
- Install **Python headers** with `sudo aptitude install python-dev`
- **Compile** with `python setup.py build`
- **Install** with `sudo python setup.by install`

  - First try *failed* with `distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate an Oracle software installation`
  - patched `setup.py` with setting `userOracleHome = "/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe"` after `os.getenv("ORACLE_HOME")`
  - `sudo python setup.by install` then worked
- **Check** with `python -c 'import cx_Oracle'` succeeded.